# Treat 2nd sheet as an extension of the 1st one for printing purposes in Excel

Tags: excel, printing

I have 2 sheets on a Excel Workbook. Both have A4 size.
I want a way to make excel treat the 2nd sheet as an extension of the 1st one for printing purposes. Maybe the software of some printers give the possibility to do this, but I want that this is to be done inside Excel, by the means of a macro or maybe some excel option allows this.

In resume: I want a way to print 1st sheet on the front of the paper and the 2nd one on the back, on a single action. How can this be done?

Comment: Yes. But that cannot be changed, at least using the software associated to them. I'm assuming we are using a printer that has duplex capability.

Comment: This MS KB article might help - [KB214383: Only the first worksheet is printed duplex in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/214383)